# The bottom 2 rows do not register touch in my tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am updating an older app to be compatible with the larger iPhone screen and latest iOS 7. I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why the last 2 rows on my UITableViews are not registering a touch. I can't select a row or scroll up/down on the bottom inch or so of my screen. I've been playing with the .xib files but nothing unusual stands out. I'm happy to paste any code samples but not sure whether that would be helpful.

Everything is displaying properly on the larger screen, but the bottom portion of the screen cannot be interacted with. My other apps did not have this problem when I updated them and I can't see any obvious differences.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

So, all it took was posting on here for me to finally realize what was wrong. Dumb mistake. The MainWindow file no longer had "Full screen at launch" selected. Checking the box fixed the issue.

Comment: I don't know how many times I have been typing a question up and I ended up fixing the problem before posting--- Sometimes thats all it takes!

Comment: thank you so much for asking and answering! I was working on some super legacy code, and I never thought of this!!!